# Enabling Unlocked Packages and 2GP on a HUB

Tags: salesforcedx, 2gp

So basically my company has a dev hub, that owns all our 1GP **enterprise** managed/unmanaged packages.

1. What will happen to 1GP packages if we turn on "Enable Unlocked Packages and Second-Generation Managed Packages"?
2. Can we guarantee that nothing will break and there is nothing to worry about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What will happen to 1GP packages if we turn on "Enable Unlocked Packages and Second-Generation Managed Packages"?

Nothing. But there's an assumption here that cannot be correct:

> my company has a dev hub, that owns all our 1GP enterprise managed/unmanaged packages.

Dev Hubs do not own 1GP managed packages - the packaging org does. Your Dev Hub may have the namespace *linked* to it, and that is fine.

> Can we guarantee that nothing will break and there is nothing to worry about?

You can never guarantee anything, but turning on 2GP is a pretty safe change. It shouldn't impact anything else in your org unless you have some integration that is exceptionally sensitive to seeing new objects in the org's Tooling API schema.